# C#: Select certain rows from datagridview

Tags: datagridview

```
        string[] column0Array = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];
        string[] column1Array = new string[dataGridView1.Rows.Count];


        int k = 0;

        List<DataGridViewRow> rows = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (rows != null)
            if (i % 4 == 0)
                rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
                // if (dataGridView1.Rows.IndexOf(i%4 == ) )


                {
                    column0Array[k] = row.Cells[0].Value != null ? row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
                    column1Array[k] = row.Cells[1].Value != null ? row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

                    k++;
                }
        }
```

Something like this? I have an exception unhandled...

Comment: dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accpeted if it works for you...

Comment: than you need to check if(rows!=null) and than in for loop need to write down foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows) rahter than full gridview loop ...I hopeyou got it

Comment: this is right what else you want..

Comment: at column0Array i have an exception : Index was outside the bounds of the array....

Comment: than check the lengh of the array is it equal to the datagridviewrow and also check the row having cell[0] and cell[1]...

Comment: got you issue ...remove inner foreach loop will resolve the problem ....i m pastin edited code

Comment: it says: the name "row" doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: take update code from the answer

Comment: It doesn't work ... Cannot implicity convert DataGridViewRow to string. 2nd error: ";" expected . 3rd error INVALID EXPRESSION TERM '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rows = null;
for (int i =0;i<dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
{
  if(i%4==0)
   rows.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[i]);

  column0Array[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value != null ? dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
  column1Array[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value != null ? dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() : string.Empty;

}
```

Comment: List<GridViewRow> rows = null; // what assembly reference should I use?

Comment: @FlorinMihalache - System.Web.UI.WebControls

Comment: using System.Web.UI.WebControls; ... hmmm, my "project" doesn't see UI ... I;m using VS 2010 Professional

Comment: @FlorinMihalache - is it web applicaiton or windows application ? if windows go for System.Windows.Forms

Comment: it is windows application, excuse me I didn't mentioned that.

Comment: @FlorinMihalache - i edited my answer you need to create list of type DataGridViewRow

Comment: it says: the name "row" doesn't exist in the current context